# What is your favourite captcha script?

Tags: captcha

I would like to gather information about popular captcha scripts in one place.
Please write links to your favourite ones!

Comment: This is not really the kind of question that Stack Overflow is here to answer. [Read this for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) Once you have a specific question about a specific problem you are having with code you are writing, feel free to return.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

1. [recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net)
2. [Textcaptcha](http://textcaptcha.com)
3. [Picaptcha](http://www.picatcha.com/#&panel1-1)
4. [Nucaptcha](http://www.nucaptcha.com/home)
5. Solvemedia etc..

But none of them are 100% useful and captchas seems out dated too because most of the spammers are humans. If you are using captcha the best solution is to [create your own captcha](http://www.webgalli.com/blog/php-captcha-security-images/) with a unique algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

http://recaptcha.net/ "recaptcha" for helping OCR-izing old books as a consequence in the worlds benefit

Answer (score 0):

previously I used [this](http://www.captcha.net/) one.But now I am creating my own like simple mathematical calculation or simple text.